# What does __ATOMIC_RELAXED mean?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic, built-in

In GCC atomic built-in I found that __atomic_exchange function does have a third parameter int memorder, which could take one of the values `__ATOMIC_RELAXED`, `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST`, `__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE`, `__ATOMIC_RELEASE`, and `__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL`.

> __ATOMIC_RELAXED:
>       Implies no inter-thread ordering constraints.

I am not sure how can that happen, isn't this supposed to be atomic operation and therefore there will not be any inter-thread ordering ?

Comment: Do you mean ordering instructions `__atomic_exchange` or ordering the `load` and `store` used by the function `__atomic_exchange` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All these builtins correspond to new C11 standard atomicity features. Standard contains perfect explanation of memory_order_relaxed ordering model and some examples (refer to 7.17.3/14)

```
// Thread 1:
r1 = atomic_load_explicit(&y, memory_order_relaxed);
atomic_store_explicit(&x, r1, memory_order_relaxed);

// Thread 2:
r2 = atomic_load_explicit(&x, memory_order_relaxed);
atomic_store_explicit(&y, 42, memory_order_relaxed);
```

This code is allowed to produce `r1 == 42 && r2 == 42.` because store of y in thread 2 might reordered before load of r2.

Answer (score 1):

`__ATOMIC_RELAXED` means that the operation itself is atomic, without there being additional ordering constraints. In other words, the operation itself is atomic: another thread will only ever see the state before or after the operation, but never an intermediate state where the operation is partially executed. However the compiler, CPU, and memory system are free to reorder the operation with respect to other operations on other variables.

(`shared = 2; tmp = shared;` with a relaxed store and load can't run as `tmp = shared; shared = 2;`.  RELAXED Operations on the *same* variable by the same thread are still ordered wrt. each other, but not wrt. anything else.  See  http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#19)

---

The gcc atomics are basically a copy of the C++11 spec, regardless of whether you use them in C or C++. Here is what the [gcc atomics manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) says (boldface emphasis on C++11 references is mine)

> The following built-in functions **approximately match the requirements
> for the C++11 memory model**. They are all identified by being prefixed
> with ‘__atomic’ and most are overloaded so that they work with
> multiple types.
>
> ⋮
>
> The description of each memory order is only meant to roughly
> illustrate the effects and is not a specification; **see the C++11
> memory model for precise semantics.**

This explains the lack of detailed description of the memory orders.
So, turning to the [C++11 spec](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), we find the following detail for `__ATOMIC_RELAXED`:

> Relaxed operation: there are no synchronization or ordering
> constraints imposed on other reads or writes, only this operation's
> atomicity is guaranteed (see Relaxed ordering below).

Comment: *free to reorder the operation with respect to other operations.* ... on other objects.  For example, compilers and hardware need to make sure `shared = 2; tmp = shared;` loads `2` (or any later but not earlier value in the modification-order of `shared` if other threads are also modifying it).  That requirement might seem obvious for basic sanity, but people have asked about so it's worth mentioning.  http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#19

Comment: @Peter Are you just saying that the compiler/HW can't reorder statements in a way that would break single-thread semantics? (That is true... but if we have to mention it, shouldn't we also mention that this applies to all statements in the program, not just the atomics primitives?)

Comment: It goes somewhat beyond not breaking single-threaded programs.  For example as the standard points out, `tmp1 = shared; tmp2 = shared;` must load in that order, not the reverse.  So if `shared` is monotonically increasing and doesn't wrap, it's guaranteed that `tmp2 >= tmp1`, even if those increments are being done by another thread or threads.  (Even if it's another thread doing `shared = local_counter++;` in a loop with relaxed stores.)  Every atomic object has its own modification-order which all threads can agree on, even in programs that use relaxed atomics.

Comment: @Peter Oh OK now I get it. I think `tmp1 = shared; tmp2 = shared;` is a better example because it could be reordered without breaking single-threaded programs, and therefore the atomic is adding an ordering restriction that we wouldn't otherwise have. Can we just replace the example in the answer? (I still don't quite get the `shared = 2; tmp = shared;` example, as it doesn't seem to be a case where the atomic adds an ordering restriction)

Comment: Go ahead and edit, you're right that read-read coherence is a better and more illustrative example than write-read which seems obviously necessary even for single-threaded code to work.  (And yet I'm pretty sure I remember at least one question about write-read, or maybe just something in comments, from someone taking an incomplete statement about `relaxed` at face value and not thinking through the consequences for single-threaded code.)