# arm gcc: store-store ordering without volatile?

Tags: gcc, arm, atomic, volatile, memory-barriers

I am trying to use a shared index to indicate that data has been written to a shared circular buffer. Is there an efficient way to do this on ARM (arm gcc 9.3.1 for cortex M4 with -O3) without using the [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118/5896591) `volatile` keyword?

The following C functions work fine on x86:

```
void Test1(int volatile* x) { *x = 5; }
void Test2(int* x) { __atomic_store_n(x, 5, __ATOMIC_RELEASE); }
```

Both compile efficiently and identically on x86:

```
0000000000000000 <Test1>:
   0:   c7 07 05 00 00 00       movl   $0x5,(%rdi)
   6:   c3                      retq   
   7:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   e:   00 00 

0000000000000010 <Test2>:
  10:   c7 07 05 00 00 00       movl   $0x5,(%rdi)
  16:   c3                      retq
```

However on ARM the `__atomic` builtin generates a [Data Memory Barrier](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/miscellaneous-instructions/dmb--dsb--and-isb), while `volatile` does not:

```
00000000 <Test1>:
   0:   2305            movs    r3, #5
   2:   6003            str     r3, [r0, #0]
   4:   4770            bx      lr
   6:   bf00            nop

00000000 <Test2>:
   0:   2305            movs    r3, #5
   2:   f3bf 8f5b       dmb     ish
   6:   6003            str     r3, [r0, #0]
   8:   4770            bx      lr
   a:   bf00            nop
```

How do I avoid the memory barrier (or similar inefficiencies) while also avoiding `volatile`?

Comment: The [multiprocessing] tag is for systems with multiple CPUs.  I assumed that's what you were talking about based on that tag.  I retagged to [memory-order] which is unfortunately a synonym of [memory-barriers] (instead of the reverse)

Comment: @Peter Actually my question is about multiprocessing. Even though gcc is compiling for a single-core device, I have connected a second, external CPU via the device's SWD interface. Does it matter how the additional CPUs are connected? I just want to prevent the first CPU (and compiled code) from reordering stores on the memory bus. The point is that there is other HW/SW looking at the memory bus. I suppose [memory-barriers] captures this just as well as [multiprocessing].

Comment: This is getting into [cpu-architecture] territory, far from the ISO C standard.  I'd assume that M4 is too simple to do any internal reordering, so its memory-bus accesses should be in program order.  It doesn't have any cache.  I think my answer probably still applies to what you're doing, but it would have been a good idea to include those details in the question in the first place, since it could perhaps be different from the normal multithreading situation on ARM where all threads are part of the same inner-shareable coherency domain.  (Thus `dmb ish` rather than `dmb sy`, for example.)

Comment: @Peter Right, there is no cache between the M4 and my external peripheral. (The M4 is integrated on a MAX32660 device with integrated memory that has a cache, but that cache is southside, between the bus and memory, and therefore doesn't change any semantics/behavior/ordering for anyone connected to the bus. Also the cache is only used for instruction fetches from NVM, per the manual.). Good point, that a different system might have different caching elements that require different barrier instructions.

Comment: @Peter On second thought, Isn't the store-store ordering a universal requirement for ARM CPUs? For example, we expect `volatile` writes to remain ordered, and we also expect them not to generate barrier instructions. (I'm still reading up on this... apparently the ARM [memory ordering spec](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102336/0100/Memory-ordering?lang=en) distinguishes between peripheral memory and RAM... Peripherals have stricter ordering... This could complicate my plans to use RAM to effectively control a peripheral, even though it's common practice on servers)

Comment: *we expect volatile writes to remain ordered,* - What?  Program order in asm matches source order in C, but there's no guarantee that anything outside the CPU core sees stores in that order. e.g. by committing from the store buffer in a different order, if a cache line is ready for a younger store while still waiting for ownership of an older store, for cacheable memory (https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/). Perhaps that doesn't happen for uncacheable memory regions; that would be helpful for writing device drivers, avoiding `dmb sy` between stores

Comment: You might still be ok on Cortex-M4, if it doesn't do any hardware memory reordering.  But that's definitely something to check on.

Comment: @Peter Ah yes, *uncacheable memory regions* is the trick that adapter cards typically use in this situation. Thank you for reminding me. (And in the case of MAX32660, we get one nice big uncacheable memory region for everybody without even lifting a finger, seeing as there's no cache). I'm pretty sure this concept is universal to all CPUs (with a possible devil in the details for any given platform).

Comment: @Peter [ARM memory barrier guide for M series](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5efefb97dbdee951c1cd5aaf?token=&usg=AOvVaw0kf0yPc2EkrkULesS5rkZp&opi=89978449) says "The Cortex-M processors never perform memory accesses out of order compared to instruction flow, however, the architecture does not prohibit this in future implementations". So M4 is OK but apparently I'll need to revisit the question when porting to other architectures. I had not realized that `volatile` only applies to compiler reordering, without behavioral ordering on general HW. Thanks for educating me.

Comment: On a CPU without cache, there'd probably be no reason to build a store buffer that could commit out-of-order.  But for other ordering properties, especially StoreLoad ordering, that doesn't come for free.  On x86, marking a memory region "uncacheable" (with MTRR registers or per-page PAT) also gives accesses to it stronger ordering semantics.  And disallows speculative access.  (e.g. it would be a disaster if a load from an MMIO register happened anyway even though it was in the non-taken side of an if/else). Related: [ARM prefetch workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46118893)

Comment: Anyway, even on an ARM without cache, there could still be a meaningful difference in marking a region of physical address-space as "device" rather than "RAM", especially if StoreLoad ordering mattered.  The docs you found for M4 confirm this is a non-problem there even for StoreLoad.  (A store buffer naturally creases StoreLoad reordering, so that's plausible even on a core without cache.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `volatile` assignment isn't a release-store, and doesn't even give you StoreStore ordering which might be all you need here.

`volatile` is basically equivalent to `__ATOMIC_RELAXED` ordering, except that it prevents compile-time reordering with other `volatile` accesses.  It does *not* do anything to prevent run-time reordering, which CPU memory models other than x86 do allow.  (As for actual atomicity, with narrow enough types you do get atomicity with certain compilers, like GCC and Clang, since the Linux kernel uses `volatile` this way to roll its own atomics, along with inline asm for fences.)

See also *[When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118)* - **never, `volatile` doesn't give you anything you can't get with atomics for the purposes of multi-threading**.   Use GNU C builtins or C++20 `std::atomic_ref` with `memory_order_relaxed` instead of `volatile` if you need non-atomic access to a variable in other parts of your program.  Or more simply use C11 `stdatomic.h` `_Atomic int` or C++11 `std::atomic<>` if you never need to point a plain `int*` at it.

---

`dmb ISHST` is at least a StoreStore barrier, so in asm you could get release semantics wrt. earlier stores but not earlier loads.  That isn't sufficient for `std::memory_order_release` aka `__ATOMIC_RELEASE` (which also requires [LoadStore ordering](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/)), so there's no way to get a compiler to use that for you.   (None of the ops or fences in [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) map to that).

So unfortunately on ARMv7 and earlier, you need a full barrier (`dmb ish`) for any standard C / C++ memory_order other than `relaxed`.  ARMv8 fixed that.

---

With `-mcpu=cortex-a53` or other **ARMv8** CPUs, `stl` is available as a release-store even in AArch32 state.  So use that to avoid an expensive `dmb ish` full-barrier for release stores or acquire loads:  https://godbolt.org/z/1hzvGMbon

```
# GCC -O2 -mcpu=cortex-a53      (or -march=armv8-a)
Test2(int*):
        movs    r3, #5
        stl     r3, [r0]       // release store
        bx      lr
```

---

### Single-core systems

On your single-core Cortex M4, all "threads" will run on the same core, so run-time memory reordering isn't possible.  An interrupt leading to a context-switch is equivalent to a signal handler in the C11 / C++11 memory models.

You can use `atomic_signal_fence` to roll your own same-core-acquire / same-core-release for `relaxed` loads/stores.

```
  // writer
 buffer[idx] = xyz;
 atomic_signal_fence(memory_order_release);  // prevent compile-time reordering, no run-time cost
 atomic_store_explicit(&shared_idx, idx, memory_order_relaxed);
```

```
  // reader
 int idx = atomic_load_explicit(&shared_idx, memory_order_relaxed);
 atomic_signal_fence(memory_order_acquire);  // prevent compile-time reordering, no run-time cost
 int tmp = buffer[idx];
```

Porting such code to multi-core by changing `atomic_signal_fence` to `atomic_thread_fence` is safe but worse for performance on some ISAs, notably ARMv8 where a separate barrier instruction is expensive, but a release-store operation can just use `stl`

Comment: I need store-store ordering only.  You're right, the `__ATOMIC_RELEASE` [spec](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) (note: gcc spec is based on C++11, even if used in C) mentions loads. Bummer. But `__ATOMIC_RELAXED` just [means the operation itself is atomic, without ordering constraints to other operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77463034/5896591), so that's not what I need either.

Comment: @personal_cloud: Right.  I wrote that opening section before noticing the part about an index into a circular buffer which implies that `relaxed` / `volatile` isn't sufficient.  I rephrased the opening section with that in mind.

Comment: `volatile` ought to be sufficient if I use it both on the data and the index. It would be a pain, but ought to work?

Comment: Good point about the `stl` instruction on ARMv8. Unfortunately I'm using a Cortex M4 -- I've updated the question.

Comment: It's interesting that the load-ordering aspect of `__ATOMIC_RELEASE` isn't an issue on x86, but is on ARM. And curious that a simple store-store ordering wasn't defined to address performance on ARM, given the popularity of the publication pattern.

Comment: @personal_cloud: Is that a multi-core M4?  If not, `atomic_signal_fence(release)` should be enough to prevent compile-time reordering between plain stores to your buffer and a later `__ATOMIC_RELAXED` store to a shared index, and every other "thread" will be running on this same core.  So run-time memory reordering is impossible, only compile-time matters.  Actually that might be sufficient even on a multi-core M4, if they can't do StoreStore or LoadLoad reordering either.

Comment: @personal_cloud: Yeah, I've sometimes wondered the same thing about exposing StoreStore ordering without LoadStore because of ARM.  I'm curious how much more efficient `dmb ishst` is than `dmb ish` on higher-end ARM cores like Cortex A77, or older performance cores like Cortex-A15.

Comment: It's a single-core M4 but I'm building custom peripheral HW that accesses memory using the SWD interface. Specifically SWD on MAX32660. Come to think of it, the documentation for the built-in DMA engine seems to ignore the whole issue... maybe my whole question is academic because the compiler is unlikely to sink the data writes past the final volatile write in the first place, and/or the builtin DMA engine is just so dog slow (and my custom HW will likely be even slower at chasing the pointer, due to SWD). Having said all that, let me try your `atomic_signal_fence(release)` suggestion...

Comment: @personal_cloud: There was never a good reason for compilers not to offer a configuration option that would treat `volatile` in in a manner suitable for use with the publication pattern.  The primary situations where it would "impede performance" would be those where it would yield a working program instead of a "faster" program that doesn't work.  Unfortunately, the authors of clang and gcc are wedded to horrible premature optimizations (assuming they know what needs to be optimized even before even the roughest design of an application has been undertaken).

Comment: I can confirm that `void Test1(int* x){__atomic_signal_fence(__ATOMIC_RELEASE); __atomic_store_n(x, 5, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);}` generates efficient code (same as a simple assignment). So you're saying this will prevent the compiler from sinking stores after the fence? (how do we know this?) If so, this clever sequence seems to be what I want.

Comment: On the other hand, `__atomic_thread_fence` generates `dmb ish` again... Drat. When can I get away with `__atomic_signal_fence`?

Comment: @personal_cloud: `signal` instead of `thread` is safe on any single-core system, or for sync between an interrupt-handler and other code on the core it runs on.  All of those are equivalent to a signal-handler interrupting a thread.  It's asynchronous but it's still the same CPU so it has to preserve the illusion of instructions running in program order, so at worst you have some interleaving of the asm effects.

Comment: As for why fences can create happens-before syncronization between relaxed ops, because the ISO C and C++ standards say so.  Related: [Memory fences: acquire/load and release/store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36824811) and [In C++, is there any effective difference between a acquire/release atomic access and a relaxed access combined with a fence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42177234) among other Q&As.

Comment: @personal_cloud: also https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/ explains fences (including fences weaker than seq_cst).  That article talks about thread_fence, which guarantees this ordering wrt. threads that might be running on other cores, which can involve special asm instructions.  Using signal_fence, the same stuff applies but only for other code running on the same core, thus compilers only have to block compile-time reordering.

Comment: Let's take the MAX32660 DMA engine as an example. It takes a pointer to data, as a write. Can we assume that if we write new data, then `__atomic_signal_fence`, then write the pointer, that the DMA engine sees the new data? My intuition says yes, because the compiler would have to refrain from store-store reordering to get the signal fence behavior. And the CPU doesn't do its own store-store reorder. So can we put this all together to conclude that `__atomic_signal_fence` prevents store-store reorder on bus? And where does this argument assume anything about the number of cores on the device?

Comment: @personal_cloud: `signal_fence` does indeed prevent compile-time reordering, leaving the question of whether memory operations on buses outside of the CPU core proper happen in CPU program-order or not.  On CPUs where runtime StoreStore reoredering doesn't happen, then yes signal_fence should be sufficient to order operations visible from outside the CPU core.  (I don't have experience with embedded devices like this, so I'm hedging a little here, but I think if the hardware memory model is effectively seq_cst (no reordering at all) then signal_fence = thread_fence = external order.)

Comment: @Peter I'll accept this answer, as `signal_fence` seems good enough for my current HW. I need to read up on what store-store ordering guarantees general ARM HW makes.